# How to send a GET request that sorts and returns data from a database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I am learning node/express/mongo by creating an Animal Crossing Critterpedia using ejs templates. I have pulled the JSON from and API and stored it in a mongo database. I have all of my images, names, etc. showing in my browser via EJS templates. I would like to sort them by name OR location OR price, depending on which button is clicked. My req.body is showing up a an empty objects in my console.

Here is my app.js

```
app.get('/critters/fish', (req, res) => {    
    const name = req.params.name;
    Fish.find({}).sort({name : 1}).exec((err, fish) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.render('fish', {fish : fish});
        }
    });
    console.log(name);
});
```

Here is my ejs template:

```
<form action="/critters/fish" method='GET'>
    <button type='text' name='name'>Sort by name</button>
</form>

<form action="/critters/fish" method='GET'>
    <button type='text' name='location'>Sort by location</button>
</form>

<form action="/critters/fish" method='GET'>
    <button type='text' name='price'>Sort by price</button>
</form>
```

Ideally, a dropdown menu would work better but I wanted to get the functionality working first.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: `GET` request doesn't have a body. You can try to add query string to url like so `<form action="/critters/fish?sortby=name"` and on the server get the value like so: `var sortby = req.query.sortby;` and to make the sorting dynamic use `var sort = {}; sort[sortby] = 1; Fish.find({}).sort(sort)`

Comment: Have you tried to log `req.query`?

Comment: Yes! ```req.query``` does return ```{ name: ' ' }``` but not the sortby query. What needs to change in the html to send that data?

Comment: It seems that the query string is not  working then. So try to add a hidden input `<input type="hidden" name="sortby" value="name">` then check the req.query.

Comment: Got it working. You are my hero. Thank you for your help!